# Java - Sort - Variable comparator

Tags: java, amazon-s3, comparison

I'm trying to sort a list of Objects based upon user input.  How can I go about having the sort method implement a variant comparator?

Example:

```
List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaryList = getObjectSummaries();
objectSummaryList.sort(Comparator.comparing(S3ObjectSummary::getKey);
```

How can I make above sort based upon getKey / getModified / other arbitrary properties as required?

Comment: Create N comparators, ask the user which one he wants to use, and use the one he chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all "keys" will be linked to getter methods, you can have a static mapping of key/getter that you use in a function:

*Note: we'll have to use raw type `Comparable` as we can't use different `Functions<S3ObjectSummary, Comparable<T>>` (even if all getters will return `Comparable<X>` objects, `X` will vary)*

```
Map<String, Function<S3ObjectSummary, Comparable>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", s3 -> s3.getKey());
map.put("modified", s3 -> s3.getModified());
// other entries
```

Then sort using:

```
objectSummaryList.sort(Comparator.comparing(map.get(compareByKey)));
```

Comment: dank, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This will helps you:

```
String sortBy = "key";
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(report -> {
    try {
        return (Comparable) report.getClass().getDeclaredField(sortBy).get(report);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("exception", e);
    }
}));
```